# Is it possible to automatically add a taxonomy term for a content type?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

How is it possible to automatically add a taxonomy term for a content type?

Is it possible to make the new added terms children of this automatically set term?

I have a content type intended for users, and I would like them to be only able to add terms that are children of a parent term of my wish; in this way, if they choose a term, it will become a child of my default term, but if they don't add a term, then the node will be tagged automatically with my term (the parent term).

Answer (score 7):

In Drupal it is possible to associate a vocabulary to a content type: Once you created your vocabulary, and added the taxonomy terms, you go to admin/structure/types, and for the content type to which you want to associate the vocabulary, you click on *manage fields*; in my example, I am going to add a vocabulary to the *Article* content type.

In the *Add new field* column I fill the fields as follows (the value you use for the field name, and to the field title can be what you like better):

> [image: screenshot]

When you click on *Save*, you get the following page. (The shown error is just because I am creating a patch for Drupal 7; it's not something you should see.)

> [image: screenshot]

Select the vocabulary you want to associate with the content type, and click *Save field settings*. In the next page, you can select the default value for the taxonomy term, which by default is *- None -*; you can select the one that is automatically set. If the user doesn't change it, it will be the value associated with the node.

> [image: screenshot]

When a user will create a node of that content type, they will see something similar to what shown in the following screenshot:

> [image: screenshot]

In my case, I selected *Overview* as default taxonomy term.

When you create your vocabulary, you can set a taxonomy term that is the parent of all the other taxonomy terms, and select it as default value for the content type.

> [image: screenshot]

In this case, *Golden apple* is child of *Apple*, which is child of *Fruits*; *Kaiser pear* is child of *Pear*, which is child of *Fruit*.
As side note, the hierarchy of taxonomy terms that are shown in the node edit form is the one defined in the vocabulary you associated with the content type; this means that, if *Apple* is not child of *Fruit* in the vocabulary I am using, then it will not be shown as child, in the node edit form. The taxonomy term widget doesn't alter the vocabulary structure.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is.

You can either do this with a custom module that implements [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or by using a module that does this for you.

I can suggest looking at http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate - which may give you some clues on how to achieve this

Comment: thanks , with prepopulate where do I modify the url?